# sound is not playing when node is touched in spritekit swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, sprite-kit

I want to have a sound when a node is clicked.
currently the code is:

```
    let sndButtonClick = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("button_click.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
```

and from touches began its

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


    for touches: AnyObject in touches {


        let location = touches.locationInNode(self)
        if playButton.containsPoint(location) {
           playButton.runAction(sndButtonClick)
            playButton.removeFromParent()

            let nextScene = GamePlayMode(size: self.scene!.size)
            nextScene.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            self.view?.presentScene(nextScene)
        }
}
```

I did the exact same thing for the collision of two nodes in gameplaymode and it works but in main menu it does not work!

I tried

```
self.runAction(sndButtonClick)
```

then

```
playbutton.runAction(sndButtonClick)
```

both didnt work

Comment: I suspect that your problem is with the next line; `playButton.removeFromParent`.  That will delete the node and cancel its actions. As an experiment change the play's `waitForCompletion` to `true`.

Comment: @PriceRingo waitForCompletion parameter means that duration of the action will be the same as the length of the audio playback, but still, action won't be executed due to fact how `runAction` method works. I described that in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why running sound action on a button doesn't work ?**

This is from the docs:

> An SKAction object is an action that is executed by a node in the
>   scene (SKScene)...When the scene processes its nodes, actions associated with those nodes are evaluated.

Means the actions for a node will run **only if the node is added to the scene**. So this has no effect :

```
playButton.runAction(sndButtonClick)
playButton.removeFromParent()
```

because you have removed the button from the scene and it will not be present in the next frame when actions should be executed. That is how `runAction` method works:

> Adds an action to the list of actions executed by the node...The new action is processed the next time the scene’s animation loop is processed.

Also, because you are immediately calling `presentScene` there will be no next frame anyways, so even if you delete `removeFromParent` statement, sound will not work, because there is no next frame.

**Why running sound action on a scene doesn't work?**

`self.runAction(sndButtonClick)` won't work because you are making a transition immediately without waiting for a next frame where the queued actions will be executed (like described above).

**Solution for the Problem**

To play the sound before transition, you have to wait for a next frame, and you can do something like:

```
runAction(sndButtonClick, completion: {
   self.view?.presentScene(nextScene)
})
```

or

```
let block = SKAction.runBlock({
   self.view?.presentScene(nextScene)
})

runAction(SKAction.sequence([sndButtonClick, block]))
```

**Preventing Leaks:**

Consider using capture list inside of a block which captures self to avoid possible strong reference cycles when needed, like this:

```
let block = SKAction.runBlock({
   [unowned self] in
   //use self here
})
```

In this particular case of yours, it should be safe to go without capture list because scene doesn't have a strong reference to the block. Only block has strong reference to the scene, but after the block is executed, because nothing retains it (no strong references to it), it will be released, thus the scene can be released correctly. But, if the block was declared as a property, or the action which executes the block was running infinitely (using `repeateActionForever` method to repeat a certain sequence), then you will have a leak for sure.

You should always override scene's deinit to see what is going on (if it is not called, something retaining the scene and causing the leak).

Comment: Thank you so much for the informative answer! problem solved!

Comment: @prival No problem :) Glad to help. As an addition, if you had a scene with a transition which has a delay before the actual transition occurs eg. `view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(someDuration))`, the sound will work as well. Of course, as long as you are running sound action on a scene itself, or on a node which is added to the scene.