# Why don't SKActions execute when inside a SKAction.run block

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I can try something like this

```
let playMusic = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("sound", waitForCompletion: false)
monster.run(playMusic)
```

and i will hear audio, but if I embed it as such

```
let playMusic = SKAction.run(){
    SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("sound", waitForCompletion: false)
}
monster.run(playMusic)
```

it will not play.
I want to put it inside a run block, so I can be more flexible with when I want to play the sound(using if statements and whatnot. In reality the monster.run will execute a sequence of actions, not just playMusic, so I can't just put if statements around the monster.run method)

Comment: It does not play because you are not assigning the play action to any node.   The play action returns an `SKAction` instance, which you do not use, so it deinitializes.

Comment: i added self.run() and it works now! Now I have a followup question. I call presentScene right after the action, and now it doesn't work. I make sure waitForCompletion is set to true, but it still won't play unless i remove the presentScene which transitions to another scene.

Comment: @user3916997 Actions are queued and executed in the next frame. When you run presentScene it is executed immediately, so sound action is never really called. Put a sound action into a sequence, and execute a transition after the sound is played.

Comment: Read here about all this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/35718498